# If $\phi:G\to\bar{G}$ is an isomorphism and if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\phi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $\bar{G}$.

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

> If $\phi:G\to\bar{G}$ is an isomorphism and if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\phi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $\bar{G}$.

I am struggling with getting started with the problem. I know that we want to show that for some $b \in \bar{G}$, then $b\phi(H)b^{-1} \in \phi(H)$ but not sure how to do it. Other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: It's really helpful if you write an isomorphism on the exponential position：like $G^{\phi}$, then $H^{\phi}h_1^{\phi}=(Hh_1)^{\phi}=(h_1H)^{\phi}=h_1^{\phi}H^{\phi}$, so it's evident to see that $\overline{H}=H^{\phi}$ is a normal group.

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, $\phi$ *epimorphism* suffices to get the claim.

Answer (score 3):

Since the isomorphism is onto, there exists $a$ such that $\phi(a)=b$, and of course it follows that $b^{-1}=\phi(a^{-1})$.

Now look again at $b\phi(H)b^{-1}$ and use the multiplicativity of $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the correct one (and probably the most simple). Let $\bar{g}\in\bar{G}$ and $y\in\phi(H)$. As already noted, $\phi$ is onto by definition of isomorphism and so $\exists h\in H,g\in G$ s.t. $y=\phi(h)$ and $\bar{g}=\phi(g).$ Now by definition of $H$ being normal, $ghg^{-1}\in H.$ Thus, $\phi(ghg^{-1})\in \phi(H).$ Finally, by definition of homomorphism, $$\phi(ghg^{-1})=\phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g^{-1})=\bar{g}y\bar{g}^{-1}.$$ Thus $\bar{g}y\bar{g}^{-1}\in\phi(H)$, which proves that $\phi(H)$ is normal in $\bar{G}$.

Sorry if my different variable choices confused you, but they are natural to me. Notice the homomorphism property allows the image of $\phi$ to be "broken up nicely" and ensure our desired result.