# Normal subgroup is still normal after isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and we have an isomorphism $\phi \colon G \to H$, how can I show that $\phi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $H$?

It seems intuitive, but the only thing I can think of for a proof is saying that the homomorphism property shows that $\phi(gng^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(n)\phi(g)^{-1} \in \phi(N)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\phi:G\to\bar{G}$ is an isomorphism and if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\phi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $\bar{G}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356274/if-phig-to-barg-is-an-isomorphism-and-if-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  In particular, it suffices to show that for all $h \in H, n \in N,$ we have $h \phi(n) h^{-1} \in \phi(N)$. With that in mind, take your equation 
$$
\phi(gng^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(n)\phi(g)^{-1} \in \phi(N)
$$
and set $g = \phi^{-1}(h)$, noting that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: thank you, the missing onto component of my proof is clear now!